# SQL Alchemy get dirty update columns on before_update

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the dirty column data on what is being updated on before_update in SQL Alchemy, as to do password validation pre update. Any ideas? I've been reading through the docs, but I cannot find the method.

Here is the doc reference: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html?highlight=before_update#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_update

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph from the documentation you linked to [before_update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_update) suggests usage of [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators) for the attribute validations.
For more fine-grained control of attribute changes see [Attribute Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html#attribute-events) documentation. Both links provide code samples.